# Why ideal lattices?

Tags: lattice-crypto

An *ideal lattice* is a lattice $\mathcal{L}(A)$ generated by a block matrix
$A = \left[ A^{(1)} \mid \dots \mid A^{(m/n)} \right]$ whose blocks $A^{(i)}$ are constructed from a vector $a^{(i)}$ and a transformation matrix $F$:
$$ A^{(i)} = F^*a^{(i)} = \left[ a^{(i)}, Fa^{(i)}, \dots, F^{n-1}a^{(i)} \right] $$
where
$$
F =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc|c}
     &  & 0^T & & & -f_0 \\ \hline
     & \ddots &  & & & -f_1 \\ 
     &  & I_{n-1} & & & \vdots \\
     &  &  & \ddots & & f_{n-1} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

This lattices have been called ideal lattices because they can be equivalently characterized as ideals in the polynomial ring $\mathcal{R} = \mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle f(x) \rangle$ where $f(x)$ is an irreducible polynomial of degree $n$ over the integers. How is this possible? An ideal in $\mathcal{R}$ would be $\langle a \rangle = \{ab \mid b \in \mathcal{R}\}$, but $A$ is generated from more than one polynomial $a$ (I identify polynomials with vectors indistinctly).

I understand that each block of $A$ is an ideal of $\mathcal{R}$ itself, but is the whole $A$ an ideal? If you have a vector of polynomials $a \in \mathcal{R}^k$, it is true that $\{Ab \mid b \in \mathbb{Z}^n\}=\mathcal{L}(A) = \mathcal{L}(a) = \{ab \mid b \in \mathcal{R}\}$?

Comment: Not every ideal in $\mathcal{R}$ may have the form you describe, of being generated by a single $a$. Such an ideal is called *principal*, and many rings (including ones of the form $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle f(x) \rangle$) have non-principal ideals. Incidentally, the block matrix you give at the top of your question is often used in cryptography as the “parity check matrix” for a “quasi-cyclic lattice,” which is typically not an ideal in $\mathcal{R}$ either.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert Yeah. My question is which type of ideals (and how are generated from this $A$) are the ideal lattices.

Comment: An ideal lattice is simply the lattice associated with an ideal--any ideal. There is no restriction on the type of ideal that can yield and ideal lattice.

Comment: @ChrisPeikert So, what is the point of this construction? Does this matrix $A$ gives us (by multiplying it with an integer vector) a lattice that coincides with principal ideals generated by the same polynomial (or vector of polynomials in our case) $a$? I don't really see why or how it works exactly.

Comment: The matrix $A$ generates (by multiplication with integer vectors) the elements of the ideal (or ideal lattice, if you prefer) generated by the $m/n$ ring elements $a^{(i)}$. (If $m/n > 1$, then that ideal may not be principal.) This is because the columns of each $A^{(i)}$ form an integral basis for the principal ideal generated by $a^{(i)}$ alone. The ideal generated by all of $A$ is the sum of those individual ideals.